# Read data efficiently from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hello I have a long list of dictionaries of the form:

```
[{'date':'2022-04-22',
  'value_1':23,
  'value_2':44},
{'date':'2022-04-21',
  'value_1':21,
  'value_2':47},
...]
```

(my actual list is very long and each dictionary has more than 3 items). I want to plot 'value_2' vs 'date'. Can I get that data effectively (i.e. without a for loop over the list)? Thank you!

Comment: you have a list, so you'll have to loop.

Comment: Answered your question below.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the list into DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = [{'date': '2022-04-22', 'value_1': 23, 'value_2': 44}, {'date': '2022-04-21', 'value_1': 21, 'value_2': 47},
       {'date': '2022-04-20', 'value_1': 27, 'value_2': 50}, {'date': '2022-04-19', 'value_1': 15, 'value_2': 33}]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['date'], df['value_2'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```